# Is there a way to use Django's static method in a CSS rule?

Tags: html, css, django

I am trying to use `background-image` css rule for a django template. I am unable to use static mode with the image url. Is there a solution or work-around for this?

Here's what I have tried to do:

```
.hero-landing {
  background: linear-gradient(
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
  ),
  url('{% static 'img/people_4.jpeg' %}');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

I can't get the url to work.

Comment: You can't process non-CSS in a CSS file. Some kind of process would have to happen before the CSS file is presented to the browser.

Comment: @ralph.m understood. I have put most of the rules on the HTML as inline styling.

Comment: Perhaps if you put the CSS in the head of the document (inside a `style` element) it might be able to work — rather than in a CSS file.